# Seperating two glass pieces with a circuit board inside

Tags: materials, glass

I want to repair an outdoor lamp (see images below) however I can't get the glass container open. The methods I found on the internet are based on glue removers or based on heat but I'm not sure this will damage the print inside, as this is what I try to repair. Note that I think it is glued, however if this is not the case please let me know.

What I tried so far:

- Wringing it with a screwdriver (the image on the side shows a clear 'edge' on top, however I can't get really deep
- Applying moderate heat

Goals:

- No damage the the circuit board inside
- No damage to the glass container (if unavoidable I prefer breaking the bottom part which does not contain LED's)
- Usage of common house tools or tools that are fairly cheap to get (and safe for me to use on a kitchen table)

Images:

Bottom view

> [image: Top view]

Top view

> [image: Bottom view]

Side view

> [image: Side view]

Related:
[Loosening glass that is vacuum](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22463/usticking-two-glass-elements-fused-by-vacuum)

Comment: Note: I tried to use the spoiler to clear space(for easier scrolling), however it looks like it does not work that way..

Comment: From the fracture marks and scratches I'm pretty sure that's plastic of some sort, not glass.  If the potting compound is clear epoxy then you probably just aren't going to get it apart.  Try scratching it with a kitchen knife or an ice pick (don't damage yourself, please).  If you can mark it with steel no harder than that, it's not glass.

Comment: I tried scratching it with a scissor (same lvl of hardness right?) and it left a scratch. Note that it is quite old (around ~10 years) and weights around 500g while not being that large and therefore I thought it would be glass. I'd actually be happy if it's not glass as I can try to grind through it with easier tools.

Comment: Yup, if it'll scratch with scissors (unless they're some pretty awesome scissors) it's not glass.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut it carefully with a hacksaw with fine tooth blade while it's held in a vise. Or cut it with a small grinder held in the vise, using a tablesaw guide.

Comment: I'll try this and update/accept it when I did

Comment: @Maarten, be careful not to damage the electrical components. Keep blowing the dust and rotating the light. Use a thin sharp blade held firmly.

Comment: I will be carefull, tomorrow I'll hop by a shop for an appropiate blad